# Register to JUnit RunListener.testRunStarted

Tags: java, junit

I would like to run a one time **setup logic** whenever my tests begin to run.
I have multiple test classes and I would like this logic to run only once before all test classes are executed.
I saw that there is a *RunListener.testRunStarted* method but it seems that in order to register for that notification I need to be the one instantiating *JUnitCore*:

```
JUnitCore jUnitCore = new JUnitCore();
jUnitCore.addListner(myListener);
jUnitCore.run(...);
```

However, I cannot control how my tests are run since they might be run through *IntelliJ* for example - and then *IntelliJ* is instantiating *JUnitCore*.

Therefore, my question is what is the best location to run setup code which should be run only once before all test classes are executed **without requiring additional configuration by the client/user running my test**?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure such a method exists. But one (hacky) workaround is to have a common base class for all your test classes that has a static initializer block. It doesn't matter which test class will be loaded, the initializer will be run exactly once (except if you fork your test runs, then it will be run once per fork).

```
public abstract class AllYourTestsAreBelongToUs{
    static{
        // initialize stuff here
    }
}

public class RealTestClass extends AllYourTestsAreBelongToUs{

    @Test
    public void someTest(){}
    @Test
    public void someOtherTest(){}

}
```